# Start a web socket server with httpd vhosts

Tags: apache, websocket

I want to start a web server in apache-HTTPD. Is it possible to start Web ocket server from HTTPD and call it using a WS URL by setting proxy passes. Please state any configurations to achieve this if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but it is really not very clear what you are trying to do.  If you want help, you will need to describe in much more detail what problem you are trying to solve.  And, it would help if you described the overall context of what you're trying to do, not just the particular solution path you are working on because there may be better ways to solve this too.

Comment: I just want to know whether we can start a web-socket service using Apache   as if we start HTTP services. can we use Apache individually for this without using any other languages.  I want to host a file in an apache and let it access using a ws url like this : ws://localhost:8080/user

Comment: A webSocket is a continuously connected socket between client and server.  It's not a request/response architecture like http is so it makes no sense to "access" a file with a ws:// url.  Just use an http URL for that.